# Is it possible to get the list of all profiles which has access to a particular tab

Tags: apex, soql, tooling-api

There are lot of profile in our org. One of the new team member deleted a tab for custom object from a sandbox. It is possible to go to other and see the accessibility manually. But it will take lot of time. Is it possible to do with soql, tooling API?

Answer (score 1):

This is not a hugely complete answer, but I have just had the same requirement.

```
SELECT Label, Type, Profile.Name
FROM PermissionSet
WHERE Id IN (
    SELECT ParentId
    FROM PermissionSetTabSetting
    WHERE Name = 'Tab_API_Name'
)
```

This should return the names of all profiles/permission sets that provide access.

Answer (score 0):

You can restore the tab settings easily with a Change Set, Ant, or SFDX (and other tools). It's not necessary to retrieve the list and restore the settings manually.

## Change Set

As a Change Set, add the tab and any profiles to restore from the other sandbox, and then deploy it to the sandbox that's missing the tab. Only the tab and the related profile settings will be affected.

## Ant/Salesforce DX Metadata API

You can build a package.xml like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
  <types>
    <members>MyTab</members>
    <name>CustomTab</name>
  </types>
  <types>
    <members>*</members>
    <name>Profile</name>
  <types>
  <version>48.0</version>
</Package>
```

Retrieve the contents, and then deploy to the other sandbox.

## Salesforce DX

You can retrieve the settings by using a metadata source retrieve. For example:

```
sfdx force:source:retrieve -m CustomTab,Profile -u sandboxalias
```

You can specify the tab name, such as:

```
sfdx force:source:retrieve -m CustomTab:MyTab,Profile -u sandboxalias
```

From there, you can actually directly deploy this to the other sandbox:

```
sfdx force:source:deploy -p force-app -u othersandboxalias
```

## Getting The List

Once you retrieve the files, you can also examine the XML files manually, such as grep, awk, etc, or finding the settings in an IDE search box.